# correct react components interaction using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's suppose I have a `Modal` component that triggers an `MODAL_CLOSE` action when the user closes it.

Let's suppose I have an application that uses `Modal` component in many different places and, in some cases I want to change the application store when the `MODAL_CLOSE` event is triggered.

Is it correct to have, say a user reducer that listens for the `MODAL_CLOSE` action to make any change to the user portion of the store? Or by doing this I'm actually creating a coupling between the user "domain" and the `Modal` component?

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: You might consider using the Modal component as a higher-order component and wrap your child component with it and decide the changes there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's fine, because it's not coupling with the component, the `connect` call is doing the coupling.
Your reducer doesn't depend on the implementation of the component or even the existence of the component, just that there is an action `MODAL_CLOSE(D?)`.
Likewise, your component is not coupled to or aware of the logic of the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's correct. You would use something like `<Modal onClose={closeModalAndDoSomethingAction}` in the places where closing it has special behavior. The `Modal` component could then either dispatch its default `onClose` action, or the special one, if provided via prop. The special action would either be something other than `MODAL_CLOSE` or maybe have something in the payload that the reducer needs to make a distinction.